# SharePoint 2013 Calenders not syncing with Outlook 2007 client

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, office-integration, sharepoint-calendar

We have newly migrated Sharepoint Farm 2013 Standard from Moss 2007. Migration has been very successful, but i am getting issues related to Outlook 2007 integration with Sp2013 Calendars:

I have a user whose environment is as follows: **User has full control on the site including list.**
Os version : windows 7 
Office version : office 2007 
Outlook version: outlook 2007

[image]
[image]

Now when user clicks on Connect to outlook button on the Calendar Ribon Control, Outlook 2007 opens up a window and confirm the settings and the calendar appears on the outlook. Then when i go back to the mailboxes and revisit the calendar, it promts for a windows login screen. Then i provide my login, but it never authenticates.

Than i see the send and receive error on the outlook with following message.

[image]

But This all works on outlook 2010 version.

Confused, why isnt outlook 2007 cooperating here....

Comment: I know SharePoint Online no longer supports integration with Office 2007 (at least not full functionality).  Does the server version support integration with Office 2007?

Comment: I am using server version not sharepoint Online. I tested it on outlook 2007 it gives me above behavior, but when i test it on outlook 2010 client it works.